# Unable to integrate javascript DNS library in cypress

Tags: javascript, dns, cypress

I had a requirement in Cypress. Where in, I want to change `dns` of request and fire the request and want to restore the previous `dns` servers. I see there is "dns" library in Javascript used for this. But am not able to integrate the same in cypress. I included `var dns = require("dns")` in `plugins/index.file`. But still am not able to use the Dns library in Cypress. Do anyone have any idea on this?

Code plugins/index.js:

```js
    module.exports = (on, config) => {
      var dns = require('dns')
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
        
      })
    }
```

`test.spec.js`:

```
//const dns = require('dns') [Tested this as the declaration in index file dint work]
         describe('', () => {
            it('test1', () => {
                let origdns = dns.get();
                dns.setServers(['dns-ip1', 'dns-ip2', 'dns-ip3'])
                cy.request({
                          method: 'GET',
                          url: 'https://www.google.com/'
                        })
                dns.setServers(origdns);
```

When I used this my Cypress thrown error as `dns is not defined/dns.get()/dns.getServers()` is not a method.

Comment: I believe this may be achieved with the module API. I've not tried it myself, but might be worth a go. This means you run the test outside of cypress and it's run in node. Take a look here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#cypress-run